# Relationship between induced map and equation $AX = XB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$\mathcal A : \mathbb C^n \mapsto \mathbb C^n$ and  $ \mathcal B : L \mapsto L$ are linear maps, $A$ and $B$ are their matrices

Let $L \subset \mathbb C^n$ be $A$-invariant subspace. $\dim(L) = k, L = \langle x_1, \dots , x_k \rangle, X = \left[x_1, \dots x_k\right] \in \mathbb C^{n\times k}$, $AX = XB$. 
 Proof that $$\mathcal Ax_j = \mathcal Bx_j \ \ \ \  j = 1, \dots, k$$ 
 $B \in \mathbb C^{k \times k}$ and $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ 
Actually, I want to show, that $\mathcal B$ is the restriction of $\mathcal A$ to $L$ and $B$ is its matrix.

Comment: $B \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times n}$, so $AX=XB \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, but $AX \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times k}$, so $k=n$?

Comment: @P Something here is incorrect. Your definition of $X$ implies that $x_1,\dots,x_k \in \Bbb C^n$, but this would imply that $L = \langle x_1,\dots,x_k \rangle \subset \Bbb C^n \neq \Bbb C^{n \times n}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I mean, that $L$ is a linear shell of $(x_1, \dots , x_k)$, where $x_1, \dots , x_k \in \mathbb C^n$. I didn't know how you usually denote it on this site.

Comment: @psl2Z $B \in \mathbb C^{k \times k}$ and $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$. So, $AX \in \mathbb C^{n \times k}$.

Comment: @Paravozik Your notation for the linear span is fine. The problem is that you wrote $L \subset \Bbb C^{n \times n}$, I suspect that you meant to say $L \subset \Bbb C^n$. Also, to your second comment, the product $Bx_j$ is not defined if $B$ has size $k \times k$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok, I got it. I've edited the task.

Comment: @Paravozik $B$ must be the matrix of $\mathcal B$ *relative to some basis* of $L$. Perhaps $B$ should be the matrix relative to the basis $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the $x_j$ are linearly independent and that $B$ is the matrix of $\mathcal B$ relative to the basis $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ of $L$.

If that is the case, then the columns $XB$ are equal to $\mathcal B(x_j) \in \Bbb C^n$. Similarly, the columns of $AX$ are equal to $\mathcal A(x_j)$. The conclusion follows.

---

In detail: let $S = (x_1,\dots,x_k)$. Then
$$
\mathcal B(x_j) = [x_1 \ \ \cdots\ \ x_k][\mathcal B(x_j)]_{S}
= [x_1 \ \ \cdots\ \ x_k][\mathcal B]_S[x_j]_{S}
= XB\,e_j,
$$
where $e_j$ denotes the $j$th standard basis vector in $\Bbb C^k$.